# Query the Newest ID in a Dataset with no Dates

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am currently working with a dataset where individuals have a unique ID, but occasionally are assigned a newer ID.  For example, an individual may have the ID "V00" and they are later given the ID "V01". I want to write a query that only pulls the row that features the most recent ID.  The IDs are updated in increments of one, so V01 is newer than V02, but V03 is newer than V02 (there are no dates to go off of).  I need to bring the other column that I am working with (Spend ($)) into the output, too.

For example, if I am given the dataset:

| ID | Spend ($) |
| --- | --- |
| V00 | 20 |
| V01 | 40 |
| W00 | 30 |
| Z00 | 50 |
| Z01 | 75 |
| Z02 | 100 |

I want a table that shows:

| ID | Spend ($) |
| --- | --- |
| V01 | 40 |
| W00 | 30 |
| Z02 | 100 |

I need guidance on how to write a SQL query (with Microsoft SQL Server) that will look to the ID and then see if there is an ID that matches on all of the other characters in the ID, but has a last digit that is 1 greater.  If it exists, I want to grab that row and not any of the rows featuring an "older" ID.

Comment: There are only 26 individuals?

Comment: There are thousands - in the example above I only included one character before the two ending numbers, but there could be many.  For example, the ID could be VX01, VXY01, VXYW01, etc.

Comment: I think you need to restructure your database. You need a customer ID and a purchase ID.

Comment: Ask yourself; how many customers do you want to support and how many purchases could a customer make.

Answer (score 0):

This should work. It isn't the prettiest, but then neither is your ID structure:

```
SELECT ID,[Spend ($)]
FROM your_table main
WHERE CAST(RIGHT(ID,LEN(ID)-PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',ID)+1) AS int) = (
  SELECT MAX(CAST(RIGHT(ID,LEN(ID)-PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',ID)+1) AS int))
  FROM your_table sub
  WHERE LEFT(sub.ID,PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',sub.ID)-1) = LEFT(main.ID,PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',main.ID)-1)
)
```

It's using PATINDEX to find the first digit of each ID. It matches what's to the left of that digit, then converts everything to the right to an int to find the highest numeric suffix.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE newest(ID VARCHAR(20), Spend DECIMAL(8,2));
INSERT INTO newest VALUES
   ('V00',20),
   ('V01',40),
   ('W00',30),
   ('Z00',50),
   ('Z01',75),
   ('Z02',100);


SELECT ID,
       Spend
FROM newest
JOIN (
  SELECT 
    CONCAT(SUBSTRING(ID,1,1) , 
    FORMAT(MAX( CAST(reverse(substring(reverse(ID),1,2)) as integer) ),'00')) as x 
  FROM newest 
  GROUP BY SUBSTRING(ID,1,1)
 ) x ON x.x=ID
```

The sub query is finding the highest ID.

Answer (score 0):

Another version. It is more verbose than needed to help illustrate the technique. The logic in the cte could easily be used for computed columns in your table (note those very important assumptions).

```
with cte as (
select left(id, len(id) - 2) as unq_id, 
right(id, 2) as ver, id, spend
from @x
)
select *, row_number() over (partition by unq_id order by ver) as rno
from cte
order by unq_id, rno;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=a021007fe67f52d8c60fc9a5ca427548) to demonstrate. Note that it is not the end solution as it selects all rows for teaching purposes.